# Swift Charts - ChartYAxis - How to display a double?

Tags: swift, swiftui-charts, linemark, axismarks

In Swift Charts can the  x/y: .value be a double, or does it have to be an integer?

[image]

I'm generating a graph that is showing hours on the Y axis. Hours is hours + minutes (as a decimal) but it only seems to work with the integers and won't take doubles. Can I use a double or do I have to do a work around?

A sample part of the code is below:

```
Chart{
        ForEach(sunriseSunset) {item in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Date", item.sunrise),
                y: .value("Sunrise", (((Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.sunrise).hour!) * 60) + (Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.sunrise).minute!))  / 60),
               // y: .value("Sunrise", (((Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.sunrise).hour!)) + (Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: item.sunrise).minute!)) * minsdecimal),
                series: .value("Date", "Sunrise")
            )
            .foregroundStyle(.orange)
            .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 300)
    .chartYAxis {
        AxisMarks(
            values: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't Double work for Y values, I would say it's quite a common type for the Y axis. Please show a reproducible example or explain why Double isn't working for you.

Comment: Can you show your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have doubles for the y axis values.
To get doubles, you could try something like this for your `y` values of `hours + minutes (as a decimal)` :

```
y: .value("Sunrise", Double(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: item.sunrise).hour!) + Double(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: item.sunrise).minute!) / 60.0),
```

You could of course have this in your `item` struct:

```
 var sunriseHour: Double {
     Double(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: sunrise).hour!) + Double(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: sunrise).minute!) / 60.0
 }
```

and call:

```
y: .value("Sunrise", item.sunriseHour),
```